# Textarea to array with columns

Tags: php, html, arrays, textarea

I ultimately want to get the text pasted into a textarea to format into an html table.
The data input into the textarea would be multiple rows and columns of data.

I have been able to get the individual rows without too much trouble but I'd need to be able to get rows AND columns in order to get them into a table properly.

One issue I have is the columns are not necessarily divided by the same character. The input tends to have multiple spaces between each column (those could be trimmed down to 1 somehow perhaps).

Here is an example of the code I have that spits out the individual lines.

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

$test = isset($_POST['test'])?$_POST['test']:"";
$testlines = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $test));
foreach($testlines as $lines) {

echo $lines . "</br>";

}
}
```

Based on a suggestion I tried using the preg_split and it now outputs a table.

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

$test = isset($_POST['test'])?$_POST['test']:"";
$testlines = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $test));

echo "<table>";
foreach($testlines as $lines) {
echo "<tr>";
$cols = preg_split('/\s+|,/',$lines);

foreach($cols as $field){
echo "<td>" . $field . "</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


}
```

Comment: You may want to provide an example of a data structure you're sending

Comment: The only real easy way to do this would be a standard (or set of) deilimter(s). You could split the table on `\n` and then something like `preg_split()` to split each row into columns based on the delimiters.

Comment: scratch that, it was my html going wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `preg_split` to divide your rows you can use several sepparators and anything a regex can express, even multiple spaces together. Here's an example of sepparating by one or more espaces, and by comma

```
$cols = preg_split('/\s+|,/',$lines)
```

Use `|` to sepparate different options of splitting. `\s` is the space character (or equivalent), and the `+` indicates one or more times of that character.

Comment: I've tested with this now, and while it does appear to split the lines into columns where the spaces are I am having some trouble outputting it.  When I do a loop it prints each column fine but sends them all in one row.

Comment: You have not started the `<table>` in the code in the original post.

Comment: I used this and it works.  Updated my code in the first post.